# Build a store products

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.6

I already insalled Magento 2.4.6 with Softaculous. How I can check this issue?
''The stock item was unable to be saved. Please try again.''

Screenshot
enter image description here
[image]
[image]

Comment: Where are you having this error ? What actions are you doing ? The screenshots doesn't seem related with the error.

Comment: I assume you clicked "Test Connection" and saw a success?  You're right in that "The stock item was unable to be saved. Please try again." is commonly related to ElasticSearch issues.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

I mean with application Magento 2.4.6 ''installation was successful!''

But I cannot display my first images products to the Storefront basic.

You can see to the admin (backend) more details.

Where is this issue?
@Cladius @danronmoon

Screenshot:
[image: backend][image]